# How to handle Solidity Custom Errors in ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, custom-errors

Since Solidity v0.8.4, [custom errors are supported](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/), also in [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1498).

How can I use them in a test? Here is an example:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

contract Contract {
    uint8 value;

    error ComparisionFailed(uint8 expected, uint8 actual);

    function setValue(uint8 _value) external {
        value = _value;
    }

    function compare(uint8 _value) external view {
        if (_value != value)
            revert ComparisionFailed({expected : value, actual : _value});
    }
}
```

The test below works, but this is a bad solution.

```js
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {ethers} from 'hardhat';

describe('Contract', function () {
  let contract: any;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    let Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory('Contract');
    contract = await Contract.deploy();
  });

  it('Should revert if value is wrong', async function () {
    const expected = 123;

    await contract.setValue(expected);

    let actual = 123;
    await expect(
        contract.compare(actual)
    ).to.be.ok;

    actual = 1
    await expect(
        contract.compare(actual)
    ).to.be.revertedWith("custom error 'ComparisionFailed(123, 1)'"); // bad solution
  });
});
```

What's the proper way to handle this and check for the error `ComparisionFailed` from the abi and the values `123` and `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function to check for custom errors:

```js
export function customError(errorName: string, ...args: any[]) {

  let argumentString = '';

  if (Array.isArray(args) && args.length) {

    // add quotation marks to first argument if it is of string type
    if (typeof args[0] === 'string') {
      args[0] = `"${args[0]}"`
    }

    // add joining comma and quotation marks to all subsequent arguments, if they are of string type
    argumentString = args.reduce(function (acc: string, cur: any) {
      if (typeof cur === 'string')
        return `${acc}, "${cur}"`
      else
        return `${acc}, ${cur.toString()}`;
    })
  }

  return `'${errorName}(${argumentString})'`
}
```

The function can also handle string type arguments properly.
Here is the solution to the example in the original post:

```js
await expect(
  contract.compare(actual)
).to.be.revertedWith(customError('ComparisionFailed', expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle custom errors from your Solidity smart contract in your application using [ethers-decode-error](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error) quite easily. This utility also allows you to extract and use the parameters from custom errors if needed.

Consider a scenario where you have a contract method called `swap`, and you want to catch a specific custom error called `InvalidSwapToken`. You can do this using the following code:

```typescript
import { ErrorDecoder } from 'ethers-decode-error'
const errorDecoder = ErrorDecoder.create([abi])

const MyCustomErrorContract = new ethers.Contract('0x12345678', abi, provider)
try {
  const tx = await MyCustomErrorContract.swap('0xabcd', 123)
  await tx.wait()
} catch (err) {
  const decodedError = await errorDecoder.decode(err)
  const reason = customReasonMapper(decodedError)
  // Prints "Invalid swap with token contract address 0xabcd."
  console.log('Custom error reason:', reason)
}

const customReasonMapper = ({ name, args }: DecodedError): string => {
  switch (name) {
    case 'InvalidSwapToken':
      // You can access the error parameters using their index:
      return `Invalid swap with token contract address ${args[0]}.`
      // Or, you could also access the error parameters using their names:
      return `Invalid swap with token contract address ${args['token']}.`
    default:
      return 'The transaction has reverted.'
  }
}
```

The example above threw an `InvalidSwapToken` custom error which has a parameter of the token address. The value of this parameter can be accessed from the `args` variable when handling the error. If your customer error doesn't have any parameters, you can ignore the `args` variable.

You can refer to [the docs](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error#custom-errors) for more examples.

Here's how the ABI of the `InvalidSwapToken` custom error with an input parameter might have looked like:

```js
const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: 'address',
        name: 'token',
        type: 'address',
      },
    ],
    name: 'InvalidSwapToken',
    type: 'error',
  },
]
```

It will be much easier if you're using Typechain as you can pass the contract interface as ABI:

```typescript
const errorDecoder = ErrorDecoder.create([MyCustomErrorContract.interface])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/reference#.revertedwithcustomerror), you can use `revertedWithCustomError`

```js
await expect(
 contract.compare(actual)
).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(contract, 'ComparisionFailed').withArgs(123, 1);
```